# Bookmarklet approach

Tags: security, cross-browser, bookmarklet, bookmarks

I am trying to write a bookmarklet that will bookmark the current page and save the link to the current page in a backend service. When I click this bookmarklet, I want this bookmarklet to show up as a small popup on the top right in browser tab (attach iframe to existing page). This popup will have options to bookmark current page. Also, there will be options search my bookmarks, tag, etc in this popup.

So far, I have not seen any such bookmarklets (from delicioius, pinboard,etc). Although there are bookmarklets to  post links to various services,  they don't let you search, see the existing list of bookmarks within in the same popup. User is forced to go to the bookmarking site in a new tab to search, etc.

I am wondering is there a reason why bookmarklets (popup within existing page) like this are not done? Are there any security reasons for this? Or will be be blocked by adblockers?

Comment: Just wanted to add how I have currently implemented the bookmarklet: when the bookmarklet is clicked, a js file from my site is loaded and attaches an iframe to the current page. I then make server side calls and target the response to the iframe in my js.

Comment: this is how most bookmarklets are done.  I'm working on a similar project ... are you still working on this ... looks almost 5 years old.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at these bookmarklets http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2007/07/useful-google-bookmarklets.html

```
javascript: (function() {
    var a = window,
    b = document,
    c = encodeURIComponent,
    d = a.open("http://www.google.com/bookmarks/mark?op=edit&output=popup&bkmk=" + c(b.location) + "&title=" + c(b.title), "bkmk_popup", "left=" + ((a.screenX || a.screenLeft) + 10) + ",top=" + ((a.screenY || a.screenTop) + 10) + ",height=420px,width=550px,resizable=1,alwaysRaised=1");
    a.setTimeout(function() {
        d.focus()
    },
    300)
})();
```